# Create multi-language installer with innosetup with custom text descriptions?

Tags: inno-setup

I see I can use message files to offer a choice of language and use the `languages` tag on individual lines to install language specific files.  But how can I setup the message files to have my custom text used in things like task and component descriptions?

TIA!!

Comment: [Inno docs actually explain this.](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) (Look for the `[Languages]` section.)

Comment: Here's the answer even though someone close the question.  There are two ways in the code CustomMessage function and ExpandConstant with the {cm:xxx} format.

Comment: As both linked duplicate questions show – the `CustomMessage` function. That's why your question was closed. Using `ExpandConstant` in code is not a good approach.

Comment: One advantage to {cm:xxx,is the default text} to provide the default text in one step.